# How to install the mobiscroll in angular project with different username?

Tags: angular, mobiscroll

I already installed the mobiscroll trial in my angular project. I want to reinstall with new username. I have the option to remove the library . But unfortunately when i try to install the mobiscroll, its logged in old username.

I have used the below command
mobiscroll config angular

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got the answer.
Step 1: Execute the command `mobiscroll logout`
Step 2: Reinstall & configure with new credentials

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

does mobiscroll logout work ? i have 2 days left on my trial and when i logged in with a new account i still get this

[image]